# Why is there so little merchandise with the Serenity logo?

Tags: firefly, serenity, merchandise

This logo seems great for T-shirts and the like. But I've only seen it a few times, in places that rapidly go out of stock, which makes me think it's not an official thing. Why, when there are so many Blue Sun and other relatively obscure references on clothing, why is the Serenity logo so hard to come by? Is there some trademark issue? Am I just missing them?

[image: Serenity logo, two concentric yellow circles with Chinese characters in the center]

Comment: Because Papyrus is an atrocity that no one wants to encourage.

Comment: Because fanboys love moderately obscure merchandise. Note the lack of Aliens t-shirts but the wealth of Weyland - Yutani stuff.

Comment: I found a perfect copy of this shirt once in February 2009 at the Universal Studios in California, in the shop outside the Terminator 3D attraction. I have never been able to find another copy since with the great quality, and unfortunately, that shirt has been getting a bit ragged over the years :-\.

Comment: It took me ten seconds on the internet to locate 5 different sources of merchandise with that precise logo on them. This feels very 'opinion based', bordering on a shopping question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's ancient and even if true at the time no longer relevant.